# Function composition in boolean operators

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, language-design, function-composition

I don't have much FP experience and I think I'm just missing a key insight from someone more versed. I'm writing a small, embedded, functional, strictly- and invariantly-typed language.

I'll be using Haskell-like syntax in this question.

The following signatures are for predefined functions with types that are what you'd expect:

```
and :: bool -> bool -> bool  -- boolean and
lt  :: int -> int -> bool    -- less than
gt  :: int -> int -> bool    -- greater than
len :: list -> int           -- list length
```

My job is to compose these functions (and constants) to form an expression which has the following signature:

```
λ :: list -> bool
```

The result of which is whether a list has a length between 1 and 99.

Constraints: This language (currently) only supports function application and function composition. No lambda expressions, no higher-order functions.

This is how far I've gotten:

```
and . ((gt 0) . len) :: list -> bool -> bool
```

This takes a list, checks if it's length is greater than 0, then a boolean and returns the "and" of both arguments.

But now I'm stuck. How would you continue from here in traditional functional languages? Is there a way to express a solution without lambdas/closures?

I'm open to add new features to the language, as long as it remains underpowered and simple.

Comment: In Haskell you could write `f x = ((gt 0) len x) && ((lt 100) len x)`. Do you accept that in your language ?

Comment: What do you mean by “no higher-order functions”?

Comment: @leftaroundabout no functions that take other functions as arguments.

Comment: @V.Semeria thank you but no, you may not define new functions, only compose existing ones.

Comment: Your language already has one higher-order function: composition.

Comment: @chepner you are correct. the limitation is for userland code.

Comment: I believe that, with that list of primitives, you can never use an argument twice. Everything there looks strictly linear: you use it, you lose it. This is known, I think, to greatly reduce the expressive power of the language. You need some duplicator, like `S` in combinatory logic or `&&&` in arrows. Or `let x = e in ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [pointfree style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) and there is a nice [tool](http://pointfree.io/) on the web for transforming Haskell code to it. Converting `f xs = (length xs > 0) && (length xs < 100)` gives `f = ap ((&&) . (> 0) . length) ((< 100) . length)`. So you are just missing the [`ap`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6-latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/src/Control-Monad.html#ap) function (see also [Understanding `ap` in a point-free function in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454650/understanding-ap-in-a-point-free-function-in-haskell)). For your application it should have type `(a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)` and be built-in along with `.`.